# How to map/analyze artifacts that only correspond to 1x1m units?

Tags: vector-grid

The archaeological site has over 4 million lithic (stone tool artifact) remains from 1 occupation level, so individual proveniencing is impossible. Instead, the lithics from each 1x1m unit, were put into a single bag. I have analyzed 100,000 of these lithics from a section of the site, and each one of those lithics have 7 corresponding features. So far everything has been recorded only on paper since I am unsure how to continue.

1) I want to incorporate this lithic analysis data onto an already existing vector based recreation of the site. I will use this to create density maps of different lithic characteristics (by size, type, retouch, completeness, etc.) and if possible do some Exploratory Data Analysis. I am a relatively new student of GIS, and honestly am not sure how to go from my hand written recordings of the lithic data to a spatially referenced and manipulable layer(?).

2) A major part of this project will be to create a workable database of the information transcribed from paper notes. I have 100,000 lithics (with 7 attribute data points each) that are spatially grouped into 1x1m units (~5,000 lithics/unit average). For the actual mapping of this information I understand that I will most likely have to group all related lithics within the same unit together (through pivot tables I think) but is there a way/is there any benefit to individually record all 100,000 lithics as their own feature with its own attribute data, while allowing me still use this information like explained in #1 above?

I know I am asking a lot and some of it is probably very basic, but my university is lacking in GIS.

Comment: A little confusing, probably because I am not an archaeology student.  But to clarify, you have 100,000 points representing stone tools (or other artifacts) that have been recorded solely on paper so far, and they are recorded into 1mx1m grids?  The density mapping is pretty straight forward as well as the analysis and I would be glad to help, I just need to know about your data so far and what format it is in.  Also do you plan on using ESRI products or FOSS4G?

Comment: Thank you for helping out! 
You are correct in all your clarification points. And I will be using ESRI products. 
All the lithic data is in paper form, so I can adapt that to whatever format is necessary. I have not actually reconstructed the site yet, as I am only getting the DEM of the site in the next couple weeks, but I'm assuming that will come in raster form. The other site features are polygons taken with a total station, but all provenience points are in relation to the site the site grid. Does that clarify it?

Comment: There is definitely a benefit to recording all the artifacts and their location individually but i think this is a cost-benefit analysis type thing as recording that many will take you a fairly long amount of time.  You will want to create a geodatabase containing your various layers all in the same projection system.  Then you will want to create a feature class of points with the attributes that you want to have.  Both of these can be googled and there are plenty of tutorials out there.  http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/creatin-957174669.htm